# How to reset the list of passwords on Windows 10

Tags: windows, passwords, windows-10

Not sure if this is the right place for it and if not please let me know. I am wanting to know if I can reset the list of used passwords for my windows machine. Every month or so it forces a password change and old passwords can't be used, I'm wondering if this list of old passwords can be wiped in any way?

Answer (score 1):

You need for local users? or it's AD users?
if local
Go to control panel> Administrative tools> Local security Policy
In the left panel find : Account policy> password policy> Max. password age
you can set for example 31 days to force change psw.
[Local Policy Group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8h1Q.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to wipe the stored old passwords, but you can configure Windows not to remember your password history:

1. Use the <kbd>WIN</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to open the Run dialog. Enter **secpol.msc** and press
   Enter.
2. Expand to "**Account Policies**" > "**Password Policy**", you'll see
   the "**Enforce password history**" setting on the right.
3. Double-click the setting and set it to remember 0 password.

Answer (score 0):

To reset Windows password, we need CMD in the login screen. But usually, we don’t have CMD in login screen of windows. So, we need to go to repair mode first. For achieving repair mode without a bootable drive, we need to do a little trick here. First, we need to restart the computer, while in booting screen we have to power it of manually.